# Extending Base DACs with reference to Custom Parent

Tags: acumatica

I have a scenario with custom Parent DAC records where for each Parent I need to extend base DACs with additional data specific to that Parent.

For example I need to store additional data for each Warehouse (INSite) record, but for each custom parent record that additional data will be different. So my Child DACs will need a key reference to the ParentDAC's key as well as the INSite's key and the additional custom data fields for that specific Parent + INSite.

In a Form/Tab maintenance screen the user would select the custom Parent record then the detail grid should present all of the existing Warehouse (INSite) records with reference fields (SiteCD, Description) and the custom fields so the user can provide the additional data for that Parent + INSite.
The child records may not exist initially (when initially configuring or if a new INSite record is created) and when being created initially they of course need to be defaulted with the SiteID from the joined INSite and current Parent ID.

[image: Maintenance screen example]

I've tried to achieve this using a 'Left Outer Join' extension table which seems to not work because of the necessity of the additional Parent record key field.

I've also tried using a PXProjection which also seems to not work because of issues with initializing the key fields of the child records to the values of the Joined INSite records.

I was able to get close to the desired functionality with a custom View delegate in the maintenance screen with the following...

```
namespace DevTest {
[Serializable]
public class ParentDAC : IBqlTable
{
    [PXDBString(10, IsKey = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Parent ID")]
    [PXSelector(typeof(ParentDAC.parentID), ValidateValue = false)]
    public string ParentID { get; set; }
    public abstract class parentID : IBqlField { }
}

[Serializable]
public class INSiteCompanion : IBqlTable
{
    [PXDBString(10, IsKey = true)]
    [PXDBDefault(typeof(ParentDAC.parentID))]
    [PXParent(typeof(Select<ParentDAC, Where<ParentDAC.parentID, Equal<Current<INSiteCompanion.parentID>>>>))]
    public virtual string ParentID { get; set; }
    public abstract class parentID : IBqlField { }

    [PXDBInt(IsKey = true)]
    public virtual int? SiteID { get; set; }
    public abstract class siteID : IBqlField { }

    [PXDBBool]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Included")]
    public virtual bool? Included { get; set; }
    public abstract class included : IBqlField { }

    [PXString(30)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Warehoue ID", Enabled = false)]
    public virtual string SiteCD { get; set; }
    public abstract class siteCD : IBqlField { }

    [PXString(60)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Description", Enabled = false)]
    public virtual string Descr { get; set; }
    public abstract class descr : IBqlField { }
}

public class ParentDACMaint : PXGraph<ParentDACMaint, ParentDAC>
{
    public PXSelect<ParentDAC> Parents;
    public PXSelect<INSiteCompanion> Sites;

    public virtual IEnumerable sites()
    {
        ParentDAC parent = Parents.Current;
        PXCache cache = Sites.Cache;
        bool wasDirty = cache.IsDirty;

        foreach (PXResult<ParentDAC, INSite, INSetup, INSiteCompanion> row in PXSelectReadonly2<ParentDAC,
                CrossJoin<INSite,
                CrossJoin<INSetup,
                LeftJoin<INSiteCompanion, On<INSiteCompanion.parentID, Equal<ParentDAC.parentID>,
                    And<INSiteCompanion.siteID, Equal<INSite.siteID>>>>>>,
                Where<Current<ParentDAC.parentID>, IsNotNull,
                    And<INSite.active, Equal<True>,
                    And<INSite.siteID, NotEqual<INSetup.transitSiteID>,
                    And<Where<ParentDAC.parentID, Equal<Current<ParentDAC.parentID>>, Or<ParentDAC.parentID, IsNull>>>>>>,
                OrderBy<Asc<INSite.siteCD>>>.Select(this))
        {
            var record = (INSiteCompanion)row;
            var site = (INSite)row;

            // Initialize Key fields
            record.ParentID = parent.ParentID;
            record.SiteID = site.SiteID;
            // Initialize reference fields
            record.SiteCD = site.SiteCD;
            record.Descr = site.Descr;
            yield return record;
        }
        cache.IsDirty = wasDirty;
    }
}
}

<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/FormTab.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    ValidateRequest="false" CodeFile="AA103000.aspx.cs" Inherits="Page_AA103000" Title="Untitled Page" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPages/FormTab.master" %>

<asp:Content ID="cont1" ContentPlaceHolderID="phDS" runat="Server">
    <px:PXDataSource ID="ds" runat="server" Visible="True" Width="100%" PrimaryView="Parents" TypeName="DevTest.ParentDACMaint">
    </px:PXDataSource>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="cont2" ContentPlaceHolderID="phF" runat="Server">
    <px:PXFormView ID="form" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" Style="z-index: 100" Width="100%" DataMember="Parents" TabIndex="100">
        <Template>
            <px:PXLayoutRule runat="server" StartRow="True"/>
            <px:PXSelector ID="edParentID" runat="server" DataField="ParentID" />
        </Template>
    </px:PXFormView>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="cont3" ContentPlaceHolderID="phG" runat="Server">
    <px:PXTab ID="tab" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="150px" DataSourceID="ds">
        <Items>
            <px:PXTabItem Text="Place Holder">
                <Template>
                    <px:PXLabel ID="PXLabel1" runat="server" AlreadyLocalized="False">Place Holder</px:PXLabel>
                </Template>
            </px:PXTabItem>
            <px:PXTabItem Text="Warehouses">
                <Template>
                    <px:PXGrid ID="PXGrid3" runat="server">
                        <Levels>
                            <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="Sites">
                                <RowTemplate>
                                    <px:PXTextEdit ID="edSiteCD" runat="server" AlreadyLocalized="False" DataField="SiteCD" DefaultLocale="" />
                                    <px:PXTextEdit ID="edDescr" runat="server" AlreadyLocalized="False" DataField="Descr" DefaultLocale="" />
                                    <px:PXCheckBox ID="edIncluded" runat="server" AlreadyLocalized="False" DataField="Included" Text="Included" />
                                </RowTemplate>
                                <Columns>
                                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="SiteCD" Width="140px" />
                                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Descr" Width="220px" />
                                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Included" TextAlign="Center" Type="CheckBox" Width="60px" />
                                </Columns>
                            </px:PXGridLevel>
                        </Levels>
                    </px:PXGrid>
                </Template>
            </px:PXTabItem>
        </Items>
        <AutoSize Container="Window" Enabled="True" MinHeight="150" />
    </px:PXTab>
</asp:Content>
```

But this too has some minor issues where the reference fields (SiteCD, Description) blank when updating the custom data and navigating to a different record (though this appears to only happen when in a Tab container -- a simple Form/Detail does not seem to have this issue). When saving and the grid refreshes the reference fields do refresh the data does persist with the correct key values.

[image]

Is there an appropriate way to achieve this type of functionality or is this the best approach? Any explanation as to the changing of the reference fields when updating fields in the grid?

Answer (score 0):

PXParent was designed to work with static primary and foreign keys only.

It closely matches those constraints inherited from the SQL database provider.

Relevant code example from [documentation](https://help-2018r1.acumatica.com/Wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=67621706-e4f4-4423-b90f-84b3b6b189c4) regarding use of parent relation:

```
    public partial class SOLine : PX.Data.IBqlTable
    {
        public class SOOrderFK : SOOrder.PK.ForeignKeyOf<SOLine>
            .By<orderType, orderNbr> { }
        public class InventoryFK : InventoryItem.PK.ForeignKeyOf<SOLine>
            .By<inventoryID> { }

        public abstract class orderType : PX.Data.IBqlField { }

        [...]
        [PXParent(typeof(SOOrderFK))]
        public virtual String OrderNbr { get; set; }
        public abstract class orderNbr : PX.Data.IBqlField { }

    [...]
    [PXForeignReference(typeof(InventoryFK))]
    public virtual Int32? InventoryID { get; set; }
    public abstract class inventoryID : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
}
```

Comment: If your use case can't be implemented at the database level with primary and foreign key constraints then you should not use the PXParent and PXForeignReference attributes.